# toolbar not visible on pages using front-page template

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar

My profile is set to show the WP toolbar when viewing the site, but on a page using the front-page.php template the toolbar space is reserved but its contents are not visible. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not included `wp_footer()`. It seems the code for the toolbar is included with this call, and `wp_head()`.

[Modifying the Toolbar](http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/modifying-the-buddypress-admin-bar/)

[Reasons Why Your Toolbar May Not be Showing](http://socialtoolbarpro.com/reasons-why-your-toolbar-may-not-be-showing/)

Comment: That is correct, the admin bar is created by hooking into `wp_footer();`. A good rule of thumb is to ALWAYS have `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` in your themes. They are extremely important hooks to have as they are used for everything from plugins to including JavaScript files properly.